# What does 'SBF', as in 'SBF program' stand for?

Tags: build-sbf

From https://docs.solana.com/developing/intro/programs:

> Programs are considered stateless since the primary data stored in a program account is the compiled SBF code

From `solana program dump -u m ${COMPUTE_BUDGET_PROGRAM} on-chain-programs/compute_budget_program.so`:

> Error: ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 is not an SBF program

From https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/faq:

> The virtual address memory map used by Solana SBF programs is fixed and laid out as follows...

**What does 'SBF', as in 'SBF program' stand for?** The term 'SBF' is not defined in https://docs.solana.com/terminology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The meaning of the SBF is Solana Bytecode Format. As I understand it is an extension and successor of BPF format used earlier (https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/28125).

For more detail see [WTF is SBFv2 and how Solana runs arbitrary code on-chain](https://bpf.wtf/sol-0x00-intro/):

> And you guessed it – the programs use a variant of the eBPF technology! To be more precise, they consist of SBF, which probably stands for **Solana Bytecode Format**.

> SBF's changes
> TL;DR: Trading compile-time checks for runtime checks.

Comment: Thanks, I made a PR to fix this: https://github.com/solana-labs/solana/pull/30419